# Barracuda Web Application Firewall WAF - HTTP - Barracuda Does Not Filter Links Clicked on Page

Tags: firewall, routing, barracuda, web-application-firewall

I am trying to figure this out.

Basically the virtual IP 192.168.1.110 will filter port 80 to the real ip address 192.168.20.110. 
I can confirm this in the logs.

When I click any link on the page (in wordpress if that matters), it will follow the link on the page www.domain.com/help.

If I type in 192.168.1.110/help it will route correctly.

I tried to create a service rule to filter:
Domain - *
URL - /*
Extended Match - *

I have also tried with more specific values.

---

Note: This environment is hosted on my workstation. I do not have access to the DNS server (if needed). I assume I can make use of host files or the Barracuda WAF host files.

Thanks.

Comment: Even if you don't have an answer, please let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

This was a mistake on my end. I assumed when accessing the website through the virtual IP (the one routed through barracuda waf), it would automatically translate other links accessed through that page. I realized to assume it did something like that, it would at least need to know which urls to convert.

Regardless I just pointed an entry in my hosts file to the virtual IP which match the hardcoded full URLS in wordpress (doens't seem to use any relative links just full absolute paths). I assume you would be doing something similar with DNS.